# Can Axios be used in new next.js 13 instead of extended next fetch api version?

Tags: axios, fetch-api, middleware, next.js13, web-standards

1. Hey guys, can I use axios with next.js 13 and still get the same results of their extended fetch api version with cache and revalidate configs ??
2. Is axios going to this web-standard thing direction ??
3. I realy love axios.intereceptors functionality , should I use next middlewares instead?

please can I have yall 2 cents?

```
My first stackoverflow question, even coding for 2 years (still) ... please vote up so I can unlock the mid dev super powers tks

`export default async function Page() {
  // revalidate this data every 10 seconds at most
  const res = await **axios.get**('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 10, cache: 'force-cache' .... } });
  const data = res.json();
  // ...
}

// does axios setup the config correctly ?
```

Answer (score 12):

If you check the documentation on "Data Fetching > Caching" they comments about the React cache() wrapper. This is a way that you should be caching other libraries or data fetching process on server side components, an example:

```js
// On getSome.js

export const getSome = cache( async() => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://...', otherAxiosConfigObject);
    const data = res.json();
    return data;
})


// On Page (or component)

export const revalidate = 10; //revalidate every 10 seconds

export default async function Page() {
  const someData = await getSome();
}
```

With this approach, you can call getSome() async function in any components, and NextJS apply deduping at building time for do only one fetch process.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, it's not currently possible to use axios to revalidate data by passing the same arguments as one might do with the fetch API.

Nonetheless, there is a workaround available as a temporary solution. You can add the following line to the top of your file :

```
export const revalidate = 3600;  // revalidate every hour
```

After doing this, all your requests will be subject to revalidation after a certain period. Please bear in mind, this is merely a temporary solution and lacks the efficiency of the fetch API.

It seems that Next.js intends to implement caching and revalidation configurations for third-party services in the future. However, as of now, this functionality is not available.

I highly recommend you refer to the Next.js documentation for more details :  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#data-fetching-without-fetch